# wglGetCurrentContext for OSX

Tags: macos, opengl

I have a program on windows that manages OpenGL contexts, (things such as making them current, destroying them, pretty much everything but the actual creation). I've recently moved to programming on a mac, and I was wondering if there is some function similar to wglGetCurrentContext for OSX. I can't seem to find the documentation for these online.

Edit: The AGL (Apple GL) framework and more specifically the function aglGetCurrentContext are all deprecated.

Comment: [`aglGetCurrentContext()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/agl/1392945-aglgetcurrentcontext)?

Comment: I'm afraid this is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for CGL (Core OpenGL).

The equivalent of `wglGetCurrentContext()` is `CGLGetCurrentContext()`. It works similarly.

There's the [OpenGL Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_intro/opengl_intro.html), but I found the CGL reference to be rather more useful. I was unable to locate the CGL reference on Apple's website, but there's a [mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20140824204714/https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGL_OpenGL/CGL_OpenGL.pdf).